# Upgrading app from IOS4 to IOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I have an IOS5 app which uses following function

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and who works perfectly on IOS4 but suddenly I discovered that this function doesn't exists on IOS5 so I had to use this other equivalent one

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Now I've got the following issue: IOS4 users are not able to install my app due to this non existing function in IOS4 and what is even worse, the app is available on Apple's App Store but is only functional of IOS5 users. Another related issue us that the app suddenly stopped working on iPads equipped with Wifi, those connected to 3G networks operate normal.

Is there anything I missed trying to compile this new app version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UIViewController's [`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) has existed since iOS 2.0. Are you sure this is what's missing or broken in your app?  Do you have compile errors or link errors or something else that shows the problem?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: the difference is the receiver of that

Answer (score 4):

You can check for existence of the property like this:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)])
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Code it this way:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(parentViewController)])
    [self.parentViewController ...];
else
    [self.presentingViewController ...];
```

(This is uncompiled, untested, etc.)

The point is that you can (and should) test for capabilities, and then act accordingly. In this case, if the iOS5 method is available, use that one. If not, use the old one, which also means its a pre-iOS5 device.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is twofold:

1. compiling your app against the latest SDK version, but also set the deployment target to the oldest version that you want to support; this will ensure that the app is listed properly in the App Store;
2. checking before using any method/feature that is only available on a later version; this will ensure that you app will not crash and can be done by means of conditional compilation, e.g.:

k

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)])
{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] eginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{}];

     // Perform work that should be allowed to continue in background

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}
#endif
```

this is quite convoluted if you have to do it in many places. You may have a look at [this very good post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html) to learn how to improve upon that example.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a category that add `presentingViewController` on iOS 4.
(It disables itself on iOS 5.)

It works seamlessly; Just include 2 files.

Please see [backward-modal](http://github.com/tanin47/backward-modal.git).

I hope this benefits you as much as it does to me; It makes your code more clean!